# RegExp one Char or number

Tags: javascript, regex

i'm trying to find Regular Expression that match just one character or a number.

for example:

match:

```
N
n
10
25
```

not match:

```
n42
1Nn
Nn
1N1n
```

Comment: Try `\b(?:[a-z]|\d+)\b` with `i` flag?

Comment: Are you saying `10` is a single number? It could be 2 single numbers.

Comment: Try [`^(?:[A-Za-z]|\d+)$`](https://regex101.com/r/sKcUGN/1/)

Comment: yes, it can be any number of digits

Comment: thanks @ctwheels . that was helpful

Comment: @AmirElsaeed I posted it as an answer :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can also use `/^(?:[a-z]|\d+)$/i` assuming you're not trying to extract those values from strings.

```js
var a = ['n42','1Nn','Nn','1N1n','N','n','10','25']
var r = /\b(?:[a-z]|\d+)\b/i

a.forEach(function(s) {
  if(r.test(s)) {
    console.log(s)
  }
})
```

Answer (score 0):

You could look for digits or a character, literally.

```js
console.log(['N', 'n', '10', '25', 'n42', '1Nn', 'Nn', '1N1n']
    .map(/./.test.bind(/^(\d+|.)$/)));
```